# How i can use multiple nib files with multiple arrays?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, nib

I am creating my iOS app, and i during that , now i have to build scrollable screen where there is image view, labels, collection view, Reviews etc (Prototype Image is attached). I am wondering is it possible to make that type of screen with UITable view using multiple Nib files? (If it is possible, kindly guide me as how i should use multiple Nib files with multiple arrays). And , if it is not possible, how else i can go for it? Kindly guide me, and sorry if thats a duplicate because i have searched but i was not able to find any good answer.
 [image: l]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches that you can do.

1. If you want to use UItableview, then you need to create multiple
   UITableviewCells, where each cells is based on the section of the design. Then you can load it by using array, as you logic stated above. For example indexpath[0] you'll load the cell with the picture(lets call this pictureCell), then indexpath[1] you'll load descriptionCell, and so on.
2. The other approach is using Scrollview, with several UIViews on a vertical stackview. And then you'll create a UIView Subclass based on the section of the design. This is usually my go to solution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback man. Actually this screen will be loaded with data that will be passed on from previous screen, which is tableview  . So kindly kindly advice me in deciding which way is better (the two ways u mentioned) to implement so that the passing of data from previous screen will be easy.? I am pretty new, so i am waiting for ur advice! Thanks

Comment: I usually go with the 2nd option. Create an empty UIViews in the viewController and then create a custom UIView for each section based on the design. Then Subclass the empty UIView in the viewController with the custom UIViews that you made for each section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "array" is refering to here, but by the look of your screenshot, I would go with a StackView inside a UIScrollView, or something like that. No need for a UITableView if you don't have a repeting pattern, you can just stack multiple views in a scroll view.
I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Actually i was practicing this screen by using multiple nibs in uitableview, and each nib needed different data and data was in form of Array. And that thing was giving too many errors. So thats why i thought of asking that question.